# How to update action data from event.detail

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components

I am working in Lighting DataTable(LWC), on rowaction I want to change the button-Icon icon name if the icon is active/inactive.

Is there any way to update the event detail data from interation

I tried with this, but not working.
`event.detail.action.iconName = "utility:open"`;

[image: Data getting on row action]

Comment: Are you trying to set the icon inside the cell dynamically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason, @track won't automatically refresh the table, so you have to copy the array back into itself. I've created a [demo](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/sRAgs0z_o/1/edit) for you.

```
import { LightningElement } from "lwc";
export default class App extends LightningElement {
  data = [];
  columns = [
    {
      label: "Name",
      fieldName: "name",
    },
    {
      type: "button-icon",
      typeAttributes: { iconName: { fieldName: "iconName" } },
    },
  ];
  connectedCallback() {
    this.data = [...Array(10).keys()].map((value) => ({
      id: value,
      name: `Demo ${value}`,
      iconName: "utility:success",
    }));
  }
  onrowaction(event) {
    if (event.detail.row.iconName === "utility:error") {
      event.detail.row.iconName = "utility:success";
    } else {
      event.detail.row.iconName = "utility:error";
    }
    this.data = [...this.data];
  }
}
```

---

```
<template>
    <lightning-datatable 
        data={data} 
        columns={columns}
        onrowaction={onrowaction}
        key-field="id"
    >
    </lightning-datatable>
</template>
```

Comment: +1 thanks @sfdcfox, although I am iterating over the data and match the row with id and setting the updated data back.. Anyway, your solution is good, I have to remove iteration.

Comment: @Sarvesh the iteration method works, too. The key is to create a new array each time.